# how to calculate gain of this LCfilter

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, filter, passive-networks

Here I plotted L-C filter circuit in spice software, at resonance frequency the output has maximum voltage 4volt whereas input is 6v,

how to calculate gain or output voltage at any frequency?

so far I noted that impedance is undefined in at resonance and somewhere I noticed Z=sqrt(L/C) without considering series resistance, but cant find out how to calculate gain or output voltage

[image]

these are following data I calculated from above circuit

```
+--------+--------+----------+-------+----------+
|Xl      |Xc      |Frequency |Q      |Bandwidth |
+--------+--------+----------+-------+----------+
|216.7948|216.7948|734.127kHz|30.9707|23.7039kHz|
+--------+--------+----------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Just use wikipedia! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can write:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{R}_1+\text{s}\text{L}}+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{\text{s}\text{C}}\right)}}}{\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{R}_1+\text{s}\text{L}}+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{\text{s}\text{C}}\right)}}}=\frac{\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{L}\text{s}}{1+\text{C}\text{s}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{L}\text{s}\right)}}{\text{R}_2+\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{L}\text{s}}{1+\text{C}\text{s}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{L}\text{s}\right)}}\tag1$$

Let \$\text{s}:=\omega\cdot\text{j}\$ where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$:

$$\left|\mathscr{H}\left(\omega\cdot\text{j}\right)\right|=\left|\frac{\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{L}\text{s}}{1+\text{C}\omega\text{j}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{L}\omega\text{j}\right)}}{\text{R}_2+\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{L}\omega\text{j}}{1+\text{C}\omega\text{j}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{L}\omega\text{j}\right)}}\right|=\frac{\frac{\left|\text{R}_1+\text{L}\omega\text{j}\right|}{\left|1+\text{C}\omega\text{j}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{L}\omega\text{j}\right)\right|}}{\left|\text{R}_2+\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{L}\omega\text{j}}{1+\text{C}\omega\text{j}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{L}\omega\text{j}\right)}\right|}\tag2$$

At resonance (using the values in your schematic):

$$\text{f}_0=\frac{10000}{94\pi}\cdot\sqrt{6000\cdot\sqrt{6140388085}-54289}\approx734.213\space\text{kHz}\tag3$$

And:

$$\left|\mathscr{H}\left(2\pi\cdot\text{f}_0\cdot\text{j}\right)\right|\approx0.668602\tag4$$

---

Using Mathemactica, I got for \$\left(2\right)\$ using your values:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to determine the transfer function of the resonating network is to use the fast analytical circuits techniques or [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371). The principle is simple: determine the various time constants of this circuit without writing a single line of algebra. There are two energy-storing elements so this is a second-order network. The denominator obeys \$D(s)=1+sb_1+s^2b_2\$. There is a gain \$H_0\$ for \$s=0\$ obtained when the capacitor is open-circuited and the inductor replaced by a short: \$H_0=\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\$. Then, reduce the excitation to 0 V (replace the input source by a short circuit) and "look" at the resistance offered by the capacitor (\$L_2\$ is short circuited) and the inductor (\$C_1\$ is open circuited) connecting terminals. You have two time constants \$\tau_1=(R_1||R_2)C_1\$ and \$\tau_2=\frac{L_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ and you can form \$b_1=\tau_1+\tau_2\$. The second-order time constant is obtained by considering \$L_2\$ open circuited while "looking" into \$C_1\$'s terminals: \$\tau_{21}=C_1R_2\$ leading to \$b_2=\tau_2\tau_{21}\$. The below drawing illustrates how to conduct this analysis:

[image]

The zero is obtained by looking at the condition in the transformed circuit which could bring a null in the output voltage: \$sL_2+R_1=0\$ leading to a zero equal to \$\omega_z=\frac{R_1}{L_2}\$. This is it, we can now assemble the pieces and rework the expression to fit the second-order polynomial form: \$H(s)=H_0\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_z}}{1+\frac{s}{Q\omega_0}+(\frac{s}{\omega_0})^2}\$ with \$H_0=\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\$, \$\omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L_2C_1\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}}}\$ and \$Q=\frac{1}{\omega_0b_1}\$. The below Mathcad sheet details these results and compare the response between the brute-force expression (*high-entropy* expression, no insight) and the *low-entropy* result in which all poles, zero and gain appear in a clear and well-ordered form. This is what FACTs bring you: the swift determination of passive/active network transfer functions by considering the physical time constants. Go FACTs in 2018!

[image]

[image]

If you excite your network with a 6-V source, the output peaks to:

[image]